# NServiceBus and Generic Event Types

Tags: nservicebus, ncqrs

I am doing some work using the NCQRS frameworks and NServiceBus 3.3.4. I have been struggling with getting some subscriptions to fire and as far as I can tell all my config is 100% correct.

After some digging I noticed that the MessageType name saved in the subscription document in Raven DB looks a bit odd. The NCQRS framework wraps the domain event in a generic typed named EventMessage'1. Now when that message is saved in the scubscription store it seems to chop off part of the name, see below:

```
Ncqrs.Nsb.EventMessage`1[[Platform.Events.Category.CategoryRemoved, Version=1.0.0.0
```

Where I would expect the name to be more along the lines of this:

```
Ncqrs.Nsb.EventMessage`1[[Platform.Events.Category.CategoryRemoved, Version=1.0.0.0]]
```

At the very least.

Could this be a bug or am I doing something wrong? My subscriptions in the app.config appear as follows:

```
  <add Messages="Ncqrs.NServiceBus.EventMessage`1[[Platform.Events.Category.CategoryRemoved, Platform.Events]], Ncqrs.NServiceBus" Endpoint="core.platform.domain" />
```

It's making me crazy!

Comment: It looks like a bug. Can you raise an issue in GitHub and if posible send us a repro?

Comment: I'm interested why you use NCQRS. What is the benefit of NCQRS in contrast to the price you pay for the unnecessary abstraction?

Comment: When the project started I liked the idea that NCQRS forced you to declare commands and events explicitly, making it much more apparent on how to modify the system when it came to it. The project was started in the early days of NSB 2 when ICommand and IEvent were not explicit. Not to mention I that I wanted to jump on the NCQRS train, which was a great learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, NServiceBus won't support this since we want to push you into using more explicit message contracts. Perhaps there is a way to configure NCQRS not to require that "EventMessage" thingy?

Comment: Thanks, I will probably just implement IEvent on my events and modify the NCQRS NServiceBus bus stuff slightly. Besides, this should drastically simplify the Unicast message mapping config. It's a nightmare with NCQRS thanks to the old "EventMessage'1".

Comment: @RossJones Hello, could you please let me know how you solved it? I mean how exactly you modified the NCQRS extension for NSB, I'm facing the same problem, I don't know if I should really keep going with NCQRS !!